# Why are $x$ and $y$ independent conditioned on $z$ if $p(x,y|z) \propto p(z|x)p(x)p(y|z)$?

Tags: probability

The reason stated in the book *Bayesian Reasoning* by Barber et al. (page 43) is that it is a function of $x$ multiplied by a function of $y$. Why is that sufficient for independence? I am also not seeing why they write "proportional to". The equation is based on the graphical model $x \rightarrow z \rightarrow y$.

Comment: How does $p(y|x,z)$ relate to $p(y|z)$?

Comment: "The reason stated ... is that it is a function of $x$ multiplied by a function of $y$." Actually the conditional independence of $x$ and $y$ conditional on $z$ is equivalent to the fact that $p(x,y\mid z)=g(x,z)h(y,z)$ for some functions $g$ and $h$. When this happens, $p(x\mid z)=cg(x,z)$ and $p(y\mid z)=\frac1ch(y,z)$ for some nonzero constant $c$.

Comment: @Did, thanks, I am seeing it now.